# Where is local variable of member function created if object is created via new?

Tags: c++, class, datamember

```
Class A
{
    int a;
    int get_a()
    {
       int d;
       return a;
    }
};

A* obj_a_ptr = new A;
int c = A->get_a();
```

Where is int d memory allocated , in heap or stack ?

Comment: 'Where is local variable of ... function created': on the stack. 'Member': irrelevant. 'If object is created via `new`': irrelevant.

Comment: The "local variable" is created whenever the function is called, and ceases to exist when the function returns.    That has no relationship whatsoever to how the object is created.    Note: since the variable is not used, the compiler may optimise it out of existence, since there would be no observable difference in the program that can be detected using standard C++  (examining the code emitted by the compiler may reveal if the variable ever exists, but that is outside the realm of standard C++)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Member functions are not that different from free functions, they only implicitly get a `this` pointer as first parameter. So your member function is more or less equivalent to (lets forget about the fact that nothing in your `A` is actually accesible, because it is all `private`)

```
int get_a(A* obj)
{
   int d;
   return obj->a;
}
```

I hope this already answers your question. Whether `obj` was allocated via `new` or not makes no difference for `d` being on the stack.

Answer (score 3):

It should be noted that the C++ specification doesn't actually mandate any specific storage area for local variables, only rules for their life-time and scope. But it's common for compilers to use the stack, as that brings some simpler handling when the scope of a function ends. And thus *all* local variables are on the stack.

In your example the storage for the variables `c` *and* `obj_a_ptr` will be on the stack.

Note that the storage for `obj_a_ptr` is on the stack as well, that is where the value of the variable is stored. For a pointer, the variable itself is on the stack (for local variables) but it might point to any suitable object (on the heap or global or anywhere else).

Answer (score 2):

The [non-static] data members of an object are considered *sub-objects*, and are stored as part of that object. So your members are "on the heap" if the encapsulating object is "on the heap". (If they weren't, what *would* be stored there?)

However, this does not affect local variables declared inside a member function. There is no need for them to be stored with the object. In fact, this would be very difficult to do at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

When an object is created then memory is allocated for its non-static data members. Member functions are not included in the memory occupied by an object except it can contain a pointer to the table of pointers to virtual functions.

So within the function `get_a` the local variable `d` has automatic storage duration. After exiting the function the memory may be used by any other function not necessary by a member function of the object.

Consider the following demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    explicit A( int x = 0 ) : x( x ) {}
    int x;
    static int a[];
    int get() const { return x; }
    void set( int x ) { A::x = x; } 
};

int A::a[100];

int main()
{
    std::cout << "sizeof( A ) = " << sizeof( A ) << '\n';
}
```

Its output is

```
sizeof( A ) = 4
```

So the size of an object of the class in this demonstrative program is exactly equal to the size of its data member `x` (in general a class can be padded with additional bytes to get an alignment).

Comment: not the downvoter, but the last sentence can be easily misunderstood as size of class would always be equal sum of its members

Comment: Second paragraph is correct, but it does not follow from the first paragraph via 'so', and the remainder of the answer is completely irrelevant.

Comment: @user207421 Showing that the object's size does not include space for `get_a()::d` might be useful. Unfortunately, that's not what Vlad's done.